# Cloudwatch alarm on lambda duration not getting triggered

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloudwatch-alarms

Cloudwatch alarm on lambda is not getting triggered even when lambda latency is breaching the threshold. In last week lambda latency went upto 15 minutes several times. Below are the alarm details.

[Alarm view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2DiE.png)

```html
EventTransformerLambdaLatencyAlarm:
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: "Alarm if EventTransformer lambda takes more than the threshold to complete"
      AlarmName: "EventTransformerTaskLatencyAlarm"
      ComparisonOperator: "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
      Dimensions:
        - Name: "FunctionName"
          Value: {Ref: EventTransformerTaskName}
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: "Duration"
      Namespace: "AWS/Lambda"
      Period: !!int "300"
      Statistic: "Maximum"
      Threshold: !!int "780000" # 13 minutes in millis
      TreatMissingData: "notBreaching"
    Type: "AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm"
```

When i click "View in metrics" in alarm console, it shows the data points well above the red line.

[Metrics breached last week](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw8mk.png)

Any suggestions will be helpful

Comment: The alarm is configured to activate when the Maximum Duration is above 13 minutes **for a period of 5 minutes**. Does the graph show metrics at 1-minute, or 5-minute intervals?

Comment: 5 minutes (since period is of 5 minutes)